# Processing (.pde) sketch on the web with multiple classes

Tags: processing

I am trying to put processing sketches with multiple .pde files(tabs or classes) on my website, but it does not seem to be working. You should be able to click and make balls appear that bounce around the screen. However, it does not seem to be registering that there is a second .pde file, and therefore, the sketch does not work fully.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="processing.min.js"></script>
<title>Projects</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/projects.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<canvas data-processing-sources="ball/Ballbounces.pde" ></canvas>
<canvas data-processing-sources="ball/Ball.pde" ></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

http://willhay.io/processing/
A regular one file sketch works fine, I think it has something to do with the fact that this sketch has a ball.pde class for the balls that are supposed to appear.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, it was as simple as typing the other .pde file you wanted to load after the one you chose like so (with a space):

```
<canvas class="project" data-processing-sources="ball/Ballbounces.pde ball/Ball.pde" ></canvas>
```